# Dependency finder for a DLL in an application

Tags: c#, dll, enums, msbuild, dependencies

I have an application that I am trying to build through the command line with MSBuild. My application is composed of a lot of projects with a lot of dependencies on each other. My question is that if there is a way to find DLL's dependent on a specific DLL. This requirement was due to the following issue.

Suppose I have a project BaseProject in my application which hosts a class Enum.cs for storing all the enums used system wide. Also there is another project called DependendentProject which has a class DependendentOnEnum.cs which uses one of the enum from Enum.cs.

### For Example

Enum.cs has the following enum

```
public enum ClassTypeEnum
        {           
            A, 
            DC, 
            MP,
            FX,
            CA,
            CD
        }
```

And DependendentOnEnum uses this enum to validate and process data according to enum type

```
void ValidateAndProcessData(int enumValue)
{
       if(enumValue == ClassTypeEnum.FX) //Line3
       {
              //ProcessData
       }
}
```

Now when the DLL of BaseProject and DependentProject. The "ClassTypeEnum.FX" in the above snippet is changed to 3.

If now some other user comes along and changes the "ClassTypeEnum" to something like this, the issue arrises

```
public enum ClassTypeEnum
            {           
                A, 
                DC, 
                MP,
                OI, //Added OI at position 3
                FX,
                CA,
                CD
            }
```

Now what our patch builder does at the production machine is that it builds all the dll for projects that have changed. Now since here only the BaseProject has changed only its DLL is build.

Due to this, the DLL of DependendentProject now starts poniting to **ClassTypeEnum.OI** instead of **ClassTypeEnum.FX**. And the whole validation process fails.

I have tried using depends.exe but it only covers system dependencies. Also I want all those DLL's that are dependent on a **specific** DLL, which it does not provide.

I know building the whole solution again is an answer, but that would be an overkill since not all projects are regularly modified.

So is there a way to build such a dependency structure? Any tool or some code snippet that builds the structure.

Comment: why not explicitly assign numeric values to the enum values?

Comment: Hi coffeeMuncher, the issue described above is one of the many issues caused by dependent dll and i want a more generic and concrete solution.

Comment: What about loading DLL based on versions?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio project files (.csproj) are just XML files. In your patch builder, you can then read the XML file to read the dependent DLL or projects and if it references the modified library (BaseProject in this case), build the project. You can find the dependent DLL under ItemGroup as shown below

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj">
  <Project>{323f9761-89f4-4405-b8b1-d6feb5b1ec89}</Project>
  <Name>ClassLibrary1</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

The above is an excerpt from a .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

You kept on referring to DLLs instead of ClassLibrary csprojs so I kept thinking DLLs, resulting in this different perspective:

```
ildasm /TEXT /HEADER ^
    "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Activities.Build\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Activities.Build.dll" ^
| grep -A 4 ".assembly extern "
```

Substitute the path for your DLL. (The carets are simply command.exe's escape character.)

This results in reference data like:

```
.assembly extern System.ServiceModel.Internals
{
  .publickeytoken = (31 BF 38 56 AD 36 4E 35 )
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

<sub>(You can get grep via [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki). You can [get GOW](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow) via Chocolatey. You can [get Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) via PowerShell. And speaking of PowerShell, you could certainly use it to do this without grep—just `grep -A n` is so darned convenient.)</sub>